# Mutiple div toggle with arrow toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi this is a two in one question. I have the following fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eyhqtjy/)

I am trying to make it so the arrow goes to a downward position when the menu is toggled open and then have the arrow return to an upward position when the menu is closed. I would like it also so that when another "Click Me" is clicked if another is open it closes the previous. It was easier for an accordion style menu, but this has multiple open and closed divs. Thoughts?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     // Toggles 1st Hidden Desktop Div
     $(".dtc-s").click(function () {
         $(".dtc-h").slideToggle(500);
         $(".dtc-h").find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     });
     // Toggles 2nd Hidden Desktop Div
     $(".dtc-two-s").click(function () {
         $(".dtc-two-h").slideToggle(500);
         $(".dtc-two-h").find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     });
     // Toggles 3rd Hidden Desktop Div
     $(".dtc-three-s").click(function () {
         $(".dtc-three-h").slideToggle(500);
         $(".dtc-three-h").find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     });
     // #1
     if ($('.dtc-one').is(':visible')) $(this).next().slideDown();
     $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
     // #2
     if ($('.dtc-two').is(':visible')) $(this).next().slideDown();
     $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
     // #3
     if ($('.dtc-three').is(':visible')) $(this).next().slideDown();
     $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)'); {}
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"I would like it also so that when another "Click Me" is clicked if another is open it closes the previous"`

For this part you can hide the 2 other divs on click like this

```
$(".dtc-s").click(function () {
     $(".dtc-h").slideToggle(500);
     $(".dtc-two-h").hide(500);
     $(".dtc-three-h").hide(500);
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/w8Lxno1x/3/)

Still looking for your first question

**Edit:**

for your first question change this line

> **$(".dtc-h")**.find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');

to this

> **$(this)**.find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');

if you want to return the arrow to its right position you might need to include a flag or add/remove a .rotation class to the element

**Edit2:** "if there is a way once a new "Click Me" is toggled can the arrow of that previous opened toggle return to its rightward position?"  [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/alexandrosHadji/budhwpxn/)

the idea:

```
     $(".dtc-two-s").find('span').removeClass('transform'); //not clicked => remove rotation
     $(".dtc-three-s").find('span').removeClass('transform'); //not clicked => remove rotation
     $(this).find('span').toggleClass('transform'); //clicked => add rotation
```

Comment: This works great, but I am wondering if there is a way once a new "Click Me" is toggled can the arrow of that previous opened toggle return to its rightward position? Currently it remains in a downward position even when a new toggle is opened.

Comment: Yes simply do removeClass("transform"); on the other two divs, updated fiddle in answer, sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

i think you want something like this

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/6eyhqtjy/3/)

```
$(this).find('span').toggleClass('transform');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
         // Toggles 1st Hidden Desktop Div
         $(".dtc-s").click(function () {
             $(".dtc-h").slideToggle(500,function(){checkAll();});
             $(".dtc-two-h").hide(500,function(){checkAll();});
             $(".dtc-three-h").hide(500,function(){checkAll();});
             $(".dtc-s").find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');

         });
         // Toggles 2nd Hidden Desktop Div
         $(".dtc-two-s").click(function () {
             $(".dtc-two-h").slideToggle(500,function(){checkAll();});
             $(".dtc-h").hide(500,function(){checkAll();});
             $(".dtc-three-h").hide(500,function(){checkAll();});
             $(".dtc-two-s").find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
         });
         // Toggles 3rd Hidden Desktop Div
         $(".dtc-three-s").click(function () {
             $(".dtc-three-h").slideToggle(500,function(){checkAll();});
             $(".dtc-two-h").hide(500,function(){checkAll();});
             $(".dtc-h").hide(500,function(){checkAll();});
             $(".dtc-three-s").find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
         });
     });
    function checkAll(){
    if ($('.dtc-one').css('display') == 'none') 
     $('.dtc-s').find('span').css('transform', '');

     if ($('.dtc-two').css('display') == 'none') 
     $('.dtc-two-s').find('span').css('transform', '');

     if ($('.dtc-three').css('display') == 'none') 
     $('.dtc-three-s').find('span').css('transform', ''); 
}
```